# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' with user selected list item

Tags: python, list, tkinter

When I do my button click it keeps throwing the error

```
Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

I am unsure what to do to fix this. I have tried to change `Frequnit` to an `int` and it doesn't work. I am unsure of the syntax to correct this.

`Frequnit` is used for user selection of just one unit from the list

```
#freecodecamp.org

import math 
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

Frequnit = {
    'Hz'  : (10**0),
    'KHz' : (10**3),
    'MHz' : (10**6),
    'GHz' : (10**9),
    'THz' : (10**12),
    }
    
#creating entry
f1 = Entry           (root)
d1 = Entry           (root, width= 4)
Gtx1 = Entry         (root, width= 4)
Grx1 = Entry         (root, width= 4)
MYSUT_TX1 = Entry    (root, width= 5)
f1.grid              (row=1, column=1)
d1.grid              (row=2, column=1)
Gtx1.grid            (row=3, column=1)
Grx1.grid            (row=4, column=1)
MYSUT_TX1.grid       (row=8, column=1)



def myClick():
    #variables
    c = (2.99 * (10**8))
    d = float(d1.get())
    f = (float(f1.get())*(Frequnit[]))
    Gtx = float(Gtx1.get())
    Grx = float(Grx1.get())
    FSPL_cal1 = round(abs((20 * math.log10(d))  + (20 * math.log10(f)) + (20 * math.log10( (4 * math.pi ) / c ))) - Gtx - Grx,2)
    FSPL_cal2 = round(abs((20 * math.log10(d))  + (20 * math.log10(f)) + (20 * math.log10( (4 * math.pi ) / c ))) - Gtx - Grx +6,2)

        #Output1 GUI
    FSPL = Label(root, text="FSPL ONE-WAY")
    FSPL2 = Label(root, text="FSPL TWO-WAY")
    
    FSPL_cal1 = Label(root, text=FSPL_cal1 )
    FSPL_cal2 = Label(root, text=FSPL_cal2)
    
    FSPL.grid       (row=6, column=0)
    FSPL_cal1.grid  (row=6, column=1) 
    FSPL2.grid      (row=7, column=0)
    FSPL_cal2.grid  (row=7, column=1) 
    
def myClick2():
    #variables
    c = (2.99 * (10**8))
    d = float(d1.get())
    f = (float(f1.get())*(10**6))
    Gtx = float(Gtx1.get())
    Grx = float(Grx1.get())
    FSPL_cal1 = round(abs((20 * math.log10(d))  + (20 * math.log10(f)) + (20 * math.log10( (4 * math.pi ) / c ))) - Gtx - Grx,2)
    FSPL_cal2 = round(abs((20 * math.log10(d))  + (20 * math.log10(f)) + (20 * math.log10( (4 * math.pi ) / c ))) - Gtx - Grx +6,2)

    MYSUT_TX = float(MYSUT_TX1.get()) 
    
    FSPL_cal1 = round(abs((20 * math.log10(d))  + (20 * math.log10(f)) + (20 * math.log10( (4 * math.pi ) / c ))) - Gtx - Grx,2)
    TargetSUT_RX = round((MYSUT_TX - FSPL_cal1),2)
    Target_TX = (TargetSUT_RX -6)
    
    MYSUT_TX = Label(root, text=TargetSUT_RX )
    Target_TX = Label(root, text=Target_TX )
    
    MYSUT_TX.grid           (row=10, column=1) 
    Target_TX.grid          (row=11, column=1) 


#creating label widget
Title =     Label( root, text="Free Space Loss Calculator")
Frequency = Label(root, text="Frequency")
Distance =  Label(root, text="Distance")
Tx_Gain =   Label(root, text="Transmit Gain")
Rx_Gain =   Label(root, text="Recieve Gain")
FSPL =      Button(root, text="Free Space Path loss Calculation", command=myClick)
MYSUT_TX=   Label(root, text="SUT Transmit Power")
TargetPW =  Button(root, text="Power Recieved at Target", command=myClick2)
MYSUT_RX=   Label(root, text="Power Recieved at target")
Target_TX=  Label(root, text="Return Power from target")
Tx_Gain1  =  Label(root, text="dB")
Rx_Gain1  =  Label(root, text="dB")
FSPL_1WAY =  Label(root, text="dB")
FSPL_2WAY =  Label(root, text="dB")


#drop down items
FrequencyUnits = StringVar()#dBm, uWatts, mWatts, Watts, KWatts, MWatts)
DistanceUnits = StringVar()
PowerUnits = StringVar()


FrequencyUnits.set  ('Hz')
DistanceUnits.set   ("Meters")
PowerUnits.set      ("dBm")


# dBm    = input()
# uWatts = 10* math.log10(1000*input())  * 10**-6
# mWatts = 10* math.log10(1000*input())  * 10**-3
# Watts  = 10* math.log10(1000*input()) 
# KWatts = 10* math.log10(1000*input())  * 10**3
# MWatts = 10* math.log10(1000*input())  * 10**6


dropFreq = OptionMenu   (root, FrequencyUnits, "Hz", "KHz", "MHz", "GHz", "THZ")
dropDist = OptionMenu   (root, DistanceUnits, "Inches", "Feet", "Yards","Meters", "Miles", "NMI")
droppower = OptionMenu  (root, PowerUnits, "dBm", "uWatts", "mWatts","Watts", "KWatts", "MWatts")
dropPRT = OptionMenu    (root, PowerUnits, "dBm", "uWatts", "mWatts","Watts", "KWatts", "MWatts")
dropRPFT = OptionMenu   (root, PowerUnits, "dBm", "uWatts", "mWatts","Watts", "KWatts", "MWatts")



#GUI lay out 
Title.grid      (row=0, column=1)
Frequency.grid  (row=1, column=0)
Distance.grid   (row=2, column=0)
Tx_Gain.grid    (row=3, column=0)
Rx_Gain.grid    (row=4, column=0)
FSPL.grid       (row=5, column=1)
MYSUT_TX.grid   (row=8, column=0)
TargetPW.grid   (row=9, column=1)
MYSUT_RX.grid   (row=10, column=0)
Target_TX.grid   (row=11, column=0)

dropFreq.grid   (row=1, column=2)
dropDist.grid   (row=2, column=2)
Tx_Gain1.grid   (row=3, column=2)
Rx_Gain1.grid   (row=4, column=2)
FSPL_1WAY.grid  (row=6, column=2)
FSPL_2WAY.grid  (row=7, column=2)
FSPL_2WAY.grid  (row=7, column=2)

droppower.grid  (row=8, column=2)
dropPRT.grid    (row=10, column=2)
dropRPFT.grid   (row=11, column=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What type does `f1.get()` return?

Comment: This question is not clear, what is the expected result? Where is the user input?

Comment: what is `f` it is not even used? and yes what is `f1.get()`

Comment: @JohnGordon As `f1.get()` is from an `Entry` widget, its type will always be `str` by default.

Comment: f1&d1 is a user input

Comment: I have updated my code for more clarafication

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 entry boxes, so my guess is that 1 is for a number entry and the 2nd is for a frequency entry.
f1 = number entry
d1 = frequency entry

If so I would code it as follows:

```
def myClick():
    for key in Frequnit.keys():
        if key == d1.get():
            result = float(f1.get()) * Frequnit[key]
            resultLabel = Label(root, text=str(result)+' '+key)
            resultLabel.pack()
```

You can't turn a whole dictionary to a number, but you can access the values by referencing the key. Saying Frequnit['Hz'] is the same as saying (10**0).
I used the for and if statements for entry validation. You can get rid of those 2 lines and use Frequnit[d1.get()] and get the same result (assuming d1 is found in the dict keys).